# Extending a delegate from a base class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, extend

I have an objc base class:

```
@protocol BaseClassDelegate;

@interface BaseClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <BaseClassDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol BaseClassDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)baseDelegateMethod;

@end
```

I am creating a swift sub-class in which I want to extend my delegate...

```
protocol SubClassDelegate : BaseClassDelegate {

    func additionalSubClassDelegateMethod();
}

class SubClass: BaseClass {

    @IBAction func onDoSomething(sender: AnyObject) {

        delegate?.additionalSubClassDelegateMethod();  <--- No such method in 'delegate'
    }
}
```

Now, when I create my sub-class, I can say it conforms to the SubClassDelegate and set the delegate. The problem is (of course), is that 'delegate' doesn't exist in this sub-class. Is there a way to tell the compiler to 'extend' my delegate into my sub-class?  (or am I being insane here and missed something obvious)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd either create a wrapper delegate to make it the correct type in `SubClass`.

```
class SubClass: BaseClass {
    var myDelegate: SubClassDelegate? {
        get { return delegate as? SubClassDelegate }
        set { delegate = newValue }
    }
    @IBAction func onDoSomething(sender: AnyObject) {
        myDelegate?.additionalSubClassDelegateMethod();
    }
}
```

Or simply cast the delegate to the expected type:

```
(delegate as? SubClassDelegate)?.additionalSubClassDelegateMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks. Second option worked although the first option looked more delegate but yielded compiler errors w.r.t. overriding the property and the type.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you can't override a property to make it more specific that the parent class. I've updated the first sample.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a more comprehensive example of how to do this. Thanks to redent84 for pointing me in the right direction.

```
protocol SubclassDelegate: ClassDelegate {
    func subclassDelegateMethod()
}

class Subclass: Class {
    // here we assume that super.delegate property exists
    @IBAction func buttonPressedOrSomeOtherTrigger() {
        if let delegate: SubclassDelegate = self.delegate as? SubclassDelegate {
            delegate.subclassDelegateMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your implementation:

```
extension SomeOtherClass: SubclassDelegate {
    let someObject = Subclass()
    someObject.delegate = self

    func subclassDelegateMethod() {
        // yay! 
    }
}
```