# Modify (or add) property attributes of parent class

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, attributes, modifiers

I'm working on building a `UICollectionView subclass` to cover up more convenient layouts in a simple way. It needs to have another delegate property to handle messages from custom `UICollectionViewLayout` class, which the `UICollectionView` class already has, so I wish the delegate property of UICollectionView handles both UICollectionViewDelegate and another custom delegate protocol.

More specifically, I'd like to build something like the followings.

```
@interface CPGridCollectionView : UICollectionView <CPGridLayoutDelegate>

// add protocol declaration to existing delegate property
@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id<UICollectionViewDelegate, CPGridLayoutDelegate> delegate;

// more additional features

@end
```

But warning came up as:

```
Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'delegate'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention
```

It seems that I need to add attributes to existing property of `UICollectionView`, without breaking the functionality of `UICollectionViewDelegate`. Is this possible in Obj-C, and how can this warning be avoided?

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911655/swift-extending-a-delegate-from-a-base-class