# Detect when UIPickerView starts changing / moving

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewdelegate

I'm trying to react to the event that a `UIPickerView` started moving (not when the row was already selected).

I have searched throughout the delegate methods, and none helped. I also tried to register a notification, but couldn't figure out any that would notify as the user puts his finger on the component and starts scrolling.

Any ideas of what alternatives are there?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I have three containers with a pickerview each. When I start interacting with the picker I want to draw a border on the container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom class of `UIPickerView` and override `hitTest(point:with:)`. Creating a protocol, you can send the current picker through a delegate method to your controller and draw whatever you like:

```
protocol CustomPickerViewDelegate: class {
    func didTapped(_ picker: CustomPickerView)
}

class CustomPickerView: UIPickerView {

    weak var myDelegate: CustomPickerViewDelegate?

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // Only test for points in your needed view
        if !self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
            return nil
        }

        // Return using CustomPickerViewDelegate the current picker
        // that can be used to determine which one was selected
        myDelegate?.didTapped(self)

        // Call super.hitTest(_: with:)
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

Do NOT forget (in your controller: eg. `YourViewController`):

`self.pickerView.myDelegate = self`.

Create an extension of your controller the subscribes to `CustomPickerViewDelegate` protocol:

```
extension YourViewController: CustomPickerViewDelegate {
    func didTapped(_ picker: CustomPickerView) {
        // do what you want here
        self.addBorderTo(picker: picker)
    }
}
```

If you like you can extend the `UIPickerViewDelegate` (see below how you can extend base class delegate)

[Extending a delegate from a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911655/extending-a-delegate-from-a-base-class)

Good luck :]

Comment: Good idea! The delegate declaration should be a weak optional and instead of setting up a second delegate, you should just set a single function optional variable.

Comment: updated answer for weak delegate. it can be done with delegate,  block, etc :)